# Undefined variable? encrypt/decrypt

Tags: javascript

Hey i am trying to make a simple encrypt/decrypt javascript. I am having a lot of trouble using variables from my first function into the second function.

the first function encrypts

2nd function decrypts

problem: I cannot use the variables I used in my first function. For example for "encoded" it keeps returning undefined! I attached my short code under.

```js
var encoded;
function code(string, pass)
{
    array=[]
    for (var i = 0; i<string.length; i++)
    {
        //converts code into an array & unicode
        b = (string.charCodeAt(i))
        array.push(b)
    }
    //encovder
    let encoded = array.map(function(x)
    {
      return x*pass
    })
    return encoded
}
(code("hello",7))

//decode
function decoded()
{
    console.log(encoded)
}
console.log(decoded())
```

Comment: You are never assigning a value to the outer `encoded` variable. You could change your code to `encoded = code("hello",7);`.

Comment: You have two separate variables, both called `encoded`. One is created by `var encoded` at the top, the other is created by `let encoded` and is local to that function.

Comment: You're overriding the outer (global) `encoded` with another variable named `encoded` but with a different scope when you write `let encoded...`. Those are two different variables, so code outside the scope of the second variable (i.e. the `code` function) don't see it, they see the global one, which is never assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the value of the function to your variable in the relevant scope:

```
var encoded;
function code(string, pass){
array=[]
for (var i = 0; i<string.length; i++){
//converts code into an array & unicode
b = (string.charCodeAt(i))
array.push(b)
}
//encovder
let encoded = array.map(function(x){
  return x*pass
})
return encoded
}
encoded = (code("hello",7));
```

By the way your result will be `NaN` because `"hello".charCodeAt(5)` is `NaN` and `NaN * number == NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't set the variable `encoded` that is defined on the first line, thus it value will be `undefined` when you try to log it.

**WHY?**

because inside `code` you redefine `encoded` on this line `let encoded = ...` and the later one [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the one defined on the first line. So, here the second one gets set and not the first one (global one).

**How to solve this?**

You either not declare a new `encoded` inside the function (so this `let encoded = ...` should become this `encoded = ...`. Or assign the returned value of `code` to the global `encoded` like this `var encoded = code("hello", 7);`.

**An example of Variable Shadowing**:

```js
var value = 5;
console.log(value); // uses the above value

function foo(){
  var value = 99; // redefining value (shadowing occur from this point)
  console.log(value); // logs the newly defined value.
}// at this point, the value (99) gets destroyed.
foo();

console.log(value); // logs 5 as it is the one belonging to this scope no matter wether the value (99) gets destroyed or not.
```

Read more about **Scopes** and **Variable shadowing** and **Variables lifetime**.